# Conditional convergence $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{(x-1)\sin 2x}{x^2-4x+5}dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Explore conditional convergence
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{(x-1)\sin 2x}{x^2-4x+5}dx$$
I tried
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{(x-1)\sin 2x}{x^2-4x+5}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin 2x}{(x-1) - \frac{2(x-2)}{x-1}}dx=$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{1} \frac{\sin 2x}{(x-1) - \frac{2(x-2)}{x-1}}dx + \int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin 2x}{(x-1) - \frac{2(x-2)}{x-1}}dx$$
but how to bound this?
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin 2x}{(x-1) - \frac{2(x-2)}{x-1}}dx < \int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin 2x}{(x-1) - 3}dx$$ the last one diverges.

Comment: With appropriate substitution you should be able to write it as $\frac{\sin a}{a}$ and get an expression in terms of [cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html) and [sin integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) which has nicely defined properties and would allow you to take a limit to infinity.

Comment: I don't see the way which leads to this substitution, can you write first action?

Comment: I wonder that two integrals are cancelled.

Comment: Is it $\frac{x-1}{(x-2)^2 +1} < \frac{1}{x-2}$ when $x >2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) is enough. On $\mathbb{R}^+$ the function $\sin(2x)$ has a bounded primitive while $\frac{x-1}{x^2-4x+5}$ is eventually decreasing to zero. The integral on $\mathbb{R}^-$ is converging by the same argument.

The residue theorem also gives:

> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{(x-1)\sin(2x)}{(x-2)^2+1}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{e^2}\left(\sin 4+\cos 4\right)}.$$

Comment: But $\frac{x-1}{x^2-4x+5}$ should be also monotone use Dirichlet's?

Comment: @Denis: it is monotonic, as soon as $|x|$ is big enough. To be precise, $\frac{x-1}{(x-2)^2+1}$ is positive and decreasing to zero over $(1+\sqrt{2},+\infty)$, negative and increasing to zero over $(1-\sqrt{2},-\infty)$.

Comment: And it doesn't matter what is when x is near 0?

Comment: @Denis: over the interval $(1-\sqrt{2},1+\sqrt{2})$ the integrand function is continuous and bounded hence it is integrable for sure.